# Is it possible to have string functions (such as strstr ) consider an array from end towards beginning in C++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string

I was wondering whether or not some of the  functions in C++ can work "in reverse" . By reverse I mean: opposite to how they normally "traverse" an array. For instance, I know that strchr returns a pointer to the first occurence of given character in the array, whereas strRchr returns last occurence of given character in an array. Do strtok, strstr and any others have the same ability? I believe such options would be very useful, e.g. : when trying to find largest palindrome; (not sure this is an adequate example...)

Comment: All the functions youve just mentioned are from the C standard library.

Comment: The C++ `<algorithms>` library can easily work over ranges in reverse (or at least those that are reversible in a sensible manner). The C - not C++ - library you're talking about however is not quite so flexible.

Comment: So doy you want to "reverse" C or C++ functions?

Comment: @Borgleader And they are all in C++.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Pavel I am working with C++, nonetheless currently using the old(as far as i can tell) library <string.h>.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, no.

The old C functions take a "start pointer", and most progress *forwards* until they hit a null terminator. That's fixed behaviour.

If you're lucky, they take a "start pointer" and a length, which is better in some ways, but also mandates a forward traversal unless the function was specifically written not to do one.

Fortunately, C++'s more modern algorithms take *iterator* pairs to specify a range, which opens up some opportunities. The true magic is that "reverse iterators" exist, things that can be `++`'d but actually go backwards into a range instead (which is something no category of pointer knows how to do). You are usually permitted to pass reverse iterators into standard algorithms to get the behaviour you want; it's all quite deliberately abstract.

I recommend reading up about C++'s algorithms, and dropping old C tech. Though C programmers certainly still exist (and C applications still, for good reason, exist), the rest of us moved on from such limitations long ago. ;)

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can do an in place reverse() of your array first, and then apply the function you want.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/